# Liferay 6.0.6 / JBOSS - How can I edit JavaScript in a portlet without constantly re-deploying?

Tags: javascript, jboss, liferay, portlet

I'm trying to fix a tricky JavaScript issue in a Liferay portlet (that also happens to run a large Flex app) and every time I make a change, I have to go back to the prompt and do an "ant deploy" on the portlet, then wait for it to deploy, then reload the page, then wait for the Flex app to load. Every time I try any minor change it takes 3-4 minutes for this whole process.

Is there a configuration or setting that will uncompress the JavaScript and allow me to directly edit the JS files on the server without re-deploying every time? I've read up some on "Developer Mode" but it doesn't seem to be working, and all the Liferay docs seem specific to Tomcat whereas I'm using JBoss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are deploying a war file, just explode it in place (in the jboss deploy directory), so rather than having one compressed file called **FlexPort.war**, you would have a directory called **FlexPort.war** which would have all the exploded content from the original WAR file.

If you update JavaScript files, you might need to clear your cache in the browser, but otherwise it should take effect right away. If you update classes, you can cause a fast re-deploy by ***touch***-ing the **WAR/web-inf/web.xml** file.

**===========================================================**

Not sure why you're not seeing the JS update, but try reproducing this sequence. It helps to have some browser tool like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) or [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) installed so you can see the response headers.

1. Retrieve the JS file directly into your browser. e.g. `http://localhost:8080/js/admin/jquery-ui-1.8.12.custom.min.js`
2. Make note of the **Last-Modified** response header.
3. Modify the JS file and save. (Make sure the filesystem timestamp of the file has changed)
4. Retrieve the JS file again. The **Last-Modified** response header should be incremented to the same value as the timestamp as the filesystem timestamp.
5. Make sure the HTTP response code is **200** and not **304**  (Not Modified).

If you are still seeing the same timestamp after the file modification:

1. It could be browser caching (See **304** comment above)
2. I suppose Liferay might be caching all the content, so changes on the file system will not take effect until you redeploy the WAR. If this is the case, try ***touch***ing the **myportlet.war/WEB-INF/web.xml** file which will cause the WAR to be redeployed. Not as efficient, but hopefully faster than reissuing the ant command.

A quickie google revealed this link about [Liferay Static Content Caching](https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/4503932). It seems Liferay may indeed be caching all this stuff in ehcache. If this is the case with your portlet app, you have 2 choices:

- Turn off caching (in dev only, of course) by setting this property in your **portal-ext.properties**: `com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.cache.CacheFilter=false`
- If Liferay registers the JMX interfaces for ehcache, you may be able to surgically remove the target items from cache through [JMX-Console](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/JMXConsole) or [twiddle](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/Twiddle). With either one, once you figure out the exact operation, you can create a batch file to execute it on demand on the command line.

Comment: Thanks. It seems like it only worked on the first time though. The WAR is a folder named "myportlet.war" and I can see and edit the files in it. I've also cleared the browser cache. I Added an alert to the JS and I can see that alert, but I've changed and removed it and I'm still seeing the first alert.

Comment: That did it. I needed to set com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.cache.CacheFilter=false in portal-ext.properties. Once I did that I could edit directly in the WAR. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Exploding the war file didn't work out for me. I get around this problem by using a [node.js script(an http static file server)](https://gist.github.com/701407). What I do is when editing the JS I copy this script to the javascript folder inside the portlet project and fire up the server(You need to install node.js on your dev machine). Then I change the references of my JS scripts in the portlet to point to static server urls. 
Eg:- In your liferay-portlet.xml,

```
<footer-portlet-javascript>/js/app.js</footer-portlet-javascript>
```

Changes to,

```
<footer-portlet-javascript>http://localhost:8888/app.js</footer-portlet-javascript>
```

After that I can just edit the files and view changes in the browser right away.

(You also have to set Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in the static file server)